# Trying to connect to SQL Server using mwaa - I'm not able to connect when I try to pass instance with host like host/instance using mssqlhook

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server-2008, airflow, mssql-jdbc, mwaa

I am trying to pass a connection string from the secrets manager to mssqlhook like this

```
mssql+pyodbc://username:password@host\instance:port/schema
```

When I tried it without instance in a lower environment, it worked fine, but in our higher environment, we have an instance when I try to connect manually to SQL Server, it's working.

But when I am using in airflow code with help of mssqlhook I get an error due to the `\` - I tried `\\` and also `//` but that did not work either.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSgTy.png)

Error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYncL.png)

Can anyone help me how to pass the connection string with instance?